# The mongoose's findOne method is not recognizing my variables?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm new to `node.js, express, and mongoose`. Below is my code.

Please note that I've hard coded the value "P4" in the `findOne` method and everything works as expected.

When I try to use the `product` variable its not being recognized by the `findOne` method.

What am i doing wrong?

```
router.get('/search', function(req, res) {
var product = req.body.product;
MyData.findOne({product: **'P4'**}, function(err, doc) { 
    if (doc)
    {
        console.log('Product Found', doc);
        res.render('index',{ids: doc});
    } 
    else if (err)
    { 
          res.redirect('/');
          console.error ('Doc Not found', doc);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: When you print the value of the product variable to console (`console.log(product)`)before the `findOne()` method, what do you get?

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Answer (score 1):

You're defining a `GET` route, which (generally) gets passed parameters using query strings. In other words, `/search?product=P4`.

This means that instead of `req.body`, you should use [`req.query`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.query) to access the `product` parameter:

```
var product = req.query.product;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Even with req.query.product, I'm only only getting the first record in the mongoDB database not matter what I set the var product (product set to P4) too. below is my console.log results:  Product Found { __v: 0,
  price: '95',
  customer: 'C100',
  quanity: '100',
  product: 'P10',
  _id: 5768c29a1546a45c49d259a0 }
GET /search?product=p4 304 109.851 ms - -
GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 12.371 ms - -
GET /images/lens-1278491_1920.jpg 304 1.109 ms - -

Comment: Update. If I hardcore 'P4' instead of using the variable substitution  for "product" the query works. There must be some issue with variables when the expression is :
 MyData.findOne({product: product}, function... However this works MyData.findOne({product: 'P4'}, function... ---Here are the results of the hard corded variable 'P4'--: P4 Product Found { __v: 0,  price: '120',customer: 'C17',  quanity: '200',  product: 'P4',....... thanks russ

Comment: Another update it appears that "product" variable in this query is being ignored by mongoose. I substituted  "random data" in the variable and still got the following--.Product Found { __v: 0,
  price: '95',
  customer: 'C100',
  quanity: '100',
  product: 'P10',..... how do I force the FindOne query to use  the variable in this statement --collection.FindOne(<variable>, function..... Thks

Comment: @Russ in your `GET` query example you're using `p4` (lowercase "p") as parameter, not `P4` (uppercase "P"). I have no idea why what would yield a result where `product` is set to `P10` (assuming that you don't have any weird Mongoose middleware active).

Comment: I did think about that, and changed it to an upper case "P"4. However, it didn't help as the <variable> in the FindOne query is being ignored regardless of what its set to, then returns the first doc from the mongoDB database, but the the doc asked for in query. Could this be a bug?

Comment: Sorry, I logged the wrong thing "res.query" and not "req.query".  I corrected that to req.query and it returned P4 also.

Comment: I found the issue thanks to Robert. That is, I had to make these 2 corrections together at the same time. This is, using req.query to capture the value correctly, and changing the findOne query to MyData.findOne({product: product}, (callback).....Thks again. Robert

Answer (score 0):

Very basic tip in coding.
Always Always console.log(the variable). If its coming undefined. Means the variable is not available at that place. Try to debug step by step.

Comment: Thanks Naraya, I'm doing that in every case. the doc returns successfully, but its the wrong document.